# Typescript function arguments proper value type of object

Tags: typescript

I'm having a bit of trouble getting they type assertions I'd like to have.

I have a function

```js
const setSetting: SetSettingFn = (key, value) => {
    if (typeof settings[key] != null) {
        settings = {
            ...settings,
            [key]: value
        }
    }
}
```

with the SetSettingFn type of:

```js
type SetSettingFn = (key: keyof AppSettings, value: AppSettings[keyof AppSettings]) => void
```

I'd like the value prop to know, based on the key that was entered the proper type to assert from that key. The above just kind of mashes all the types in `AppSettings` into one flat type with everything.

For example if settings.foo is boolean, then this should throw a type error:
`setSetting('foo', 1)`

Comment: Couldn't you just do `settings[key] = value` instead of `settings = {...settings, [key]: value}`?

Comment: perhaps `typeof AppSettings[keyof AppSettings]`?

Comment: I could, right now typescript complains about that though - because of the improper typing for value. I went around that problem by desctructuring. The typing part is the actual issue, and I'm not sure how to tell typescript to narrow the type of value

Comment: AppSettings is a type, so it doesn't like typeof AppSettings, because its a type not a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say, `AppSettings[keyof AppSettings]` you are allowing *any* key to be selected from `AppSettings`. You need to tell TypeScript that you mean the specific key that is the first parameter to be used to ascertain the value type. Something like this:

```js
let settings: Record<string, any> = {};
const setSetting: SetSettingFn = (key, value) => {
    if (typeof settings[key] != null) {
        settings = {
            ...settings,
            [key]: value
        }
    }
}

type AppSettings = {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}

type SetSettingFn = < K extends keyof AppSettings = keyof AppSettings>(key: K, value: AppSettings[K]) => void

setSetting('foo', 1);
// Error: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.(2345)

setSetting('foo', 'string');
// OK
```

Link to TS Playground: https://tsplay.dev/NDzv4W

Comment: This works, could you explain what its actually doing? ```K extends keyof AppSettings = keyof AppSettings``` at first blush seems like its just renaming what I already had

Comment: I am restricting exact key here. I am saying, use the same key as parameter named key when determining type of value. If your case you are saying, parameter names could be any key AppSettings (which is fine), and the parameter named value can be of any value type mentioned in AppSettings. Mine is indicating that I want to use the same key's value type as the second param, yours is allowing any value type as long as it is in AppSettings.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you so much!